# Is there a word, phrase, or idiom for a person who stays too late at an event such as a dinner party?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, american-english, idiom-requests

Something like "latecomer" but for departing rather than arriving.

For example, "Bob was always the _____ at social outings."

Other variations with verbs or non - noun idioms are useful to me as well, such as "Bob would always ________ at social outings."

Comment: You mean he "overstays his welcome"?  ("Wears out his welcome" is also idiomatic, as suggested by Nathaniel.)

Comment: Not only did he wear out his welcome, but his hosts.

Comment: Wow, this blew up! Thanks for all the creative answers.

Comment: Dorothy Parker said that after a party's two drinks, she's under the weather. After three, under the coffee table. And after four, under the host.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Guests who stay too long can be said to **overstay their welcome** or **wear out their welcome**.  That is, their host grows tired of their presence and wishes they would leave.

The idiom is not limited to "staying too late," and also applies to other sorts of unwelcome behavior:

> To behave in an offensive, burdensome, or tiresome manner, with the result that one's continued presence is unwanted within a residence, commercial establishment, or social group. ([WT](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wear_out_one%27s_welcome))

The *overstay* variant, though sometimes considered synonymous with the *wear out* version, more strongly emphasizes the length of the visit.  It is more commonly used in British English ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=overstay+*+welcome%2Cwear+out+*+welcome&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Coverstay%20%2A%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Boverstay%20their%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boverstay%20my%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boverstay%20his%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boverstay%20your%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boverstay%20our%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boverstay%20its%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cwear%20out%20%2A%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20your%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20their%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20his%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20my%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20our%20welcome%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Coverstay%20*%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Boverstay%20their%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boverstay%20my%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boverstay%20his%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boverstay%20your%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boverstay%20our%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boverstay%20its%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cwear%20out%20*%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bwear%20out%20your%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20their%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20his%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20my%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20our%20welcome%3B%2Cc0)), while *wear out* is more popular in American English ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=overstay+*+welcome%2Cwear+out+*+welcome&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Coverstay%20%2A%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Boverstay%20your%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boverstay%20their%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boverstay%20my%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boverstay%20his%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boverstay%20our%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boverstay%20her%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boverstay%20its%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cwear%20out%20%2A%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20your%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20their%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20my%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20his%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20its%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20our%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20her%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20the%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20a%20welcome%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Coverstay%20*%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Boverstay%20your%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boverstay%20their%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boverstay%20my%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boverstay%20his%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boverstay%20our%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boverstay%20her%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boverstay%20its%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cwear%20out%20*%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bwear%20out%20your%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20their%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20my%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20his%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20its%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20our%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20her%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20the%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwear%20out%20a%20welcome%3B%2Cc0)).

The verb **overstay** by itself also communicates the act of staying too long, but less idiomatically ([WT](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overstay)).  If you require a noun, some derive **overstayer** ([WT](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overstayer)) from the verb, as used in a [LifeHacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5920945/how-to-get-rid-of-people-whove-overstayed-their-welcome):

> People won't always get your subtle hints. Sometimes you need to tell an **overstayer** directly that the conversation and hang out time is over.

Comment: Or [*outstay one's welcome*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224577/to-outstay-vs-overstay-ones-welcome)

Comment: Now, in shakespearian spirit, we need to think of a new word to identify the concept

Comment: It's a pity that *overstay* works, but the dominant (and only in the dictionaries I've just checked online) definition of *overstayer* is in the sense of immigration.

Comment: As a brit I find `outstay` more idiomatic than `overstay` ...ngram link is too long to post in a comment but seems to confirm

Comment: @Hellreaver perhaps 'lingerer' as suggested by WillB3

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone. I like 'overstay their welcome' over 'wear out' for brevity.

Comment: @CharlesParr Interesting comment about brevity.  My initial thought was that

Comment: @CharlesParr - Erm, just found that you've accepted this answer for "overstay their welcome". Is this really what you were looking for? Because, if so, I a) owe [Mari-Lou A](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/282923/91730) and [A.P.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/282820/91730) apologies and b) suggest you edit your question to reflect what you were actually looking for. (Please see comments below A.P.'s answers if you don't understand.)

Comment: ...continued.  `wear out their welcome` rolls off the tongue more easily and one less syllable.  I suppose brevity can apply to man attributes, length of text, number of syllables, duration of spoken phrase, etc.

Comment: @AndyT Thanks for the tip, I believe the question better reflects the accepted answer after my edit. I removed the noun tag as well.

Comment: @RobertL Good point regarding brevity - seems I was measuring brevity by the duration of the spoken phrase attribute.

Answer (score 20):

The word "[straggler](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/straggler)" comes to mind, meaning "a person or an animal that is among the last or the slowest in a group to do something, for example, to finish a race or leave a place."

[Example sentences](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/straggle):

> ‘The majority have returned to breeding grounds by late March, but stragglers have lingered locally until the end of May.’
>
> ‘The library was nearly deserted except for a few stragglers checking out books or reading in corners.’
>
> ‘No, the last stragglers, the tourists and the visitors, have now left the palace.’

Answer (score 18):

It may be a bit slang, but I immediately thought of the word **lingerer**, as used in *Pineapple Express*:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sN0K1NS6b8

> F***in' **lingerer**, man.

(Said after kicking someone out of his apartment).

Comment: I'm not sure I've heard it in usage much, but I'd definitely understand this if  used, and in my opinion meets the OP's requirements better than other answers.

Comment: Great! 'Lingerer' describes the phenomenon in a social context very well. Too bad I need a more formal word!

Comment: Lingerer has long usage, and is perhaps archaic and unusual, but not slang.  As the OED explains:

lingerer  
(ˈlɪŋgərə(r))  
[f. linger v. + -er1.]  
One who, or that which, lingers, tarries, etc.; a dawdler, idler; one who hankers (after).
_1579 Tomson Calvin's Serm. Tim. 610/2 As oft as we play the lingerers, & cold staruelinges. 1646 Gaule Cases Consc. 3 Our late leaners and lingerers after such a kinde of sect. 1713 Steele Guardian No. 131 ⁋1 The mighty body of lingerers, persons who..waste away In gentle inactivity the day. 1740 J. Love Cricket (1770) i. 53 O Flee, you Ling'rer, Flee!_

Answer (score 8):

**laggard**

> : someone who takes more time than necessary; someone who lags behind [Princeton University Wordnet](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/laggard)

**dawdler**

> dawdle: to take more time than necessary: *dawdled through breakfast.* [The American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/slowpoke)

*"Bob was always the laggard at parties, dawdling around and leaving after everyone else"*

Answer (score 5):

I would refer to such a person as a *hanger-on*.

My particular idiom comes from Glasgow in Scotland. I wouldn't regard this expression as particularly regional, however, and would expect it to be understood throughout the UK or even beyond.

Comment: I'd understand a hanger-on to be an additional person, someone who hangs around with an invitee perhaps, and not someone who hangs on after everyone else has left. (Southern England)

Comment: I live in the US, and I was going to suggest this.  I believe that it would be recognized here as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

I'll offer ["last man standing"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Last+Man+Standing) - the connotation of being able to carry on partying when everyone else has run out of steam.

In particular the connotations of the victor in some endurance feat. This doesn't convey the same 'outstaying welcome' connotations as some of the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

He'll stay *till the last dog is hung*.

> "When anybody from around here wanted to say they were still present at the end of a big party, they would say they had 'stayed until the last dog was hung.' Most of them probably had no idea anymore that they were talking about the Seneca New Year's celebration in the winter, where on the fifth day they used to strangle a white dog and hang it on a pole, Nobody had done that for at least a hundred years." --- *Dance for the Dead*, by Thomas Perry (Random House, New York, 1996)

Comment: That is... disturbing. And not a phrase I've ever heard. And now not one I ever want to hear...

Comment: +1 because that phrase was the first thing I thought of when I read the question. I heard it often when I was young, and never understood what the dog-hanging was about. Now I know. Is "hangdog expression" related?

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly, no one has suggested this aphorism attributed to Benjamin Franklin in 1736

> Guests, like fish, begin to smell after three days.

In the 16th century, guests who seemingly had taken permanent residence were compared to three-day-old fish. The following quote is by John Lyly (1554-1606)

> Fish and guests in three days are stale.

Source: [Dictionary of Proverbs](https://books.google.it/books?id=7PMZJqSR4sAC&pg=PA203&lpg=PA203&dq=fish%20and%20guests%20in%20three%20days%20are%20stale.&source=bl&ots=ATgsRzLAQ1&sig=8RZfs66-rzPTpHOn_5KU6msAN0E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEcQ6AEwB2oVChMI9K3RvJfiyAIVC74UCh1ZDw3Q#v=onepage&q=fish%20guests%20%20three%20days%20are%20stale.&f=false)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The OP wants a noun (or noun-phrase) for someone who stays too late, not a proverb or aphorism.

Comment: @AndyT It's a phrase, and it's idiomatic. it's a common enough saying, very well-known, and something you would say in private to your partner, or family about a person who has exceeded or is notorious for overstaying their welcome : "Bob needs to stay the night? Oh, we can't invite Bob round. He's like that  saying about guests and fish that stink/smell  after three days"

Comment: Your usage example sounds rather contrived to me. It sounds even more contrived if you try and put it in the OP's example sentence: "Bob was always the *person like that saying about guests and fish that stink/smell after 3 days* at social outings." It doesn't work.

Comment: We agree to disagree about my example of usage.

Comment: Yep, agree to disagree. And thanks for your advice on how to use my votes. If you're interested in my reasoning: "overstayer" saves the top answer from my downvote, but doesn't earn it an upvote. Based on your comment I have found some other answers which need my downvote though.

Comment: @AndyT I hope you are equally zealous in your upvotes :)

Comment: The expression is well known (to me), but your answer made me wonder why the expression hasn't been refined and come into more common use as in: _'he/she is a bad fish, he/she always overstays his/her welcome.'_  The explanation for our shying away from calling someone a _'bad fish'_ may well be that the term is a little too confronting, and that some other (much less complimentary) interpretations have already staked out territory on that expression, see: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=badfish

Comment: @JohnMack I posted this "answer" not because I thought it fit the OP's request, it doesn't, but because it is a very well-known aphorism, it is said about a guest who stays longer than his or her host would prefer, (which is what the question is about) and simply because I like it!

Comment: @Mari-LouA - If you don't think it fits the OP's request, but is related to the topic, it should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @AndyT leave me alone, stop trolling me. Thank you.

Comment: Mari Lou, sorry but Andy is right. You answer is better suited as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the expression **"closing time"**:

> the time at which pubs must legally stop selling alcoholic drinks

(http://www.thefreedictionary.com/closing+time)

By extension, this also means the very end of a social gathering.

So you could say something like: **"Bob would never leave a party before closing time"**.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The OP wants a noun (or noun-phrase) for someone who stays too late, not a complete phrase which gives the meaning without using such a noun.

Comment: The question is not tagged "noun", Andy. But it *is*  tagged "idiom". My answer provides an idiom. Thanks for at least adding a comment after downvoting. That is all I have to say on this.

Comment: A tag of "idiom" does not mean "please give me an idiom relating to this, ignoring anything else I've written". If the question asked "what's a word to describe someone who tries to please the boss" and tagged it *idiom* a correct answer might be "brown-noser", but a bad answer might be "you've got your head so far up our boss's arse that when he yawns we see your face".

Comment: Oh, and just because a new user has missed the "noun" tag doesn't mean that clarification within the rest of his question should be ignored.

Comment: Andy, I think your mind-reading powers are truly impressive with regard to what tags users miss. Also, great idiom about the boss's arse. Thanks, it's been an education.

Comment: Not mind-reading powers, word reading powers. Here are the bits you obviously missed from the question - 1. *Something like "latecomer"*. You'll see that "latecomer" is a noun. The OP wants something like that, i.e. **a noun**. 2. *For example, "Bob was always the _____ at social outings."* You'll see that, following the rules of English, the "_____" needs to be replaced with **a noun**. It is therefore a simple conclusion that the OP is looking for a noun, whether or not he has tagged the question with that.

Comment: Andy, your word-reading powers are amazing. One day, I hope to be just like you. Thank you, good sir, for not giving up on me and trying to teach me. I accept your tutelage gratefully. Thank you, and have a great day. P.S. In my (weak and unworthy) defense I can only say that "time" in "closing time" is a noun. I know it's a lame excuse.

Comment: My apologies, the OP has now clarified and it was indeed me who misunderstood what he was looking for.

Comment: No problem, my comments were tongue-in-cheek anyway. No hard feelings, Andy.

Answer (score 1):

My father once told the joke about how to get guests who have worn out their welcome to leave: "Wife, let's go to bed so our guests can go home."

Comment: Hi @Doris, welcome to EL&U. I find your answer funny but I need you to recognize that this does not answer OP's question but is still somewhat related to the question. You could post it in comment section if it's available to you

Comment: @Doris, my father would say the same thing.  I've never heard anyone else ever use that phrase.

Comment: My father-in-law would say to the guest: "Me - I still have a guest so I can't go to bed yet. But you? Don't you think it's a bit late to still be up?"

Answer (score 1):

This may not be pertinent to parties, but night owl is a term which is generally used to refer anyone who stays up late at night.

Answer (score 0):

The 'thing that wouldn't leave' has always been my favorite

Answer (score 0):

"party killer", as coined by the NYC band Mongrel Bitch: "I'm a party killer and I'm not going home, as long as there"s beer you'll never be alone"...